# Trouble inputting string at specific point in another string

Tags: java, string

```
package num20;

import TurtleGraphics.KeyboardReader;

public class Num20main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
    System.out.println("Enter String");
    String sentence = reader.readLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentence);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    //String e = "egg";
    for(int x = 0; x < sentence.length(); x++){
        String e = "egg";
        char l = sb.charAt(x);
        int index = x;
        if(l == ('a') || l == ('A') || l == ('e') || l == ('E') || l == ('I') || l == ('i') || l == ('O') || l == ('o') || l == ('U') || l == ('u')){
            sb.insert(index, e);
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

}

}
```

This code prints out:

> Enter String
>
> I Love Java
>
> I Love Java
>
> eggI Love Java
>
> eggeggI Love Java
>
> eggeggeggI Love Java
>
> eggeggeggeggI Love Java
>
> eggeggeggeggI Love Java

It's supposed to print out "eggI Leggovegge Jeggavegga"

Answer (score 1):

You are adding in the beginning of your String.
so what is happening is that you add "egg", but your index don't move forward.
"I love java" 'I' is at index 0.
but when you add a "egg", we have "eggI love java".
now 'I' is at index 3, but your x is 1 at this point.

The easiest way to do it, is run your for on the opposite way:

```
for(int x = sentence.length()-1 ; x <= 0 ; x--){ //The content of your for here }
```

Doing this, adding the "egg" will not interfere on your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    String sentence = "I love Java";
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" ")).map(str -> str.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", "fruit$0")).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Basically, you are first doing a case insensitive find and then replace the match with the match + "fruit".

Answer (score 0):

Your index moves at the same speed as x, but every replacement, you insert 3, not 1 character.

I took a fixed String for easy testing and for easy control added the exepected result in the end:

```
public class Num20 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "I Love Java";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sentence);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        // String e = "egg"; Good idea to declare this unchanged variable
        // here, but let us call it 'egg'. 
        String egg = "egg";
        int index = 0; // index out of loop 
        for (int x = 0; x < sentence.length(); x++){
            char l = sb.charAt (index); // sb is under constant change, 
            // we need to insert at a the place of sb, not sentence
            // hence we use the faster moving index 'index', not 'x'
//            if (l == ('a') || l == ('A') || l == ('e') || l == ('E') || l == ('I') || l == ('i') || l == ('O') || l == ('o') || l == ('U') || l == ('u')) {
            // not wrong, but more brief:
            if ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf (l) != -1) {
                sb.insert (index, egg);
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                // we inserted 3 characters before the vowel 
                index +=3;
            }
            // we have to forward one (more) step for every x in sentence, too:
            ++index;
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        System.out.println("eggI Leggovegge Jeggavegga?");
    }
}
```